# Bcache directory not showing up after make-bcache

Tags: azure, ubuntu, bcache

I'm setting up bcache on an ubuntu virtual machine on azure. I'm following the instructions from http://blog.rralcala.com/2014/08/using-bcache-in-ec2.html.

After running `make-bcache -B /dev/sdc1`, the `/dev/bcache0` device is not yet available.

When running `make-bcache -B /dev/sdc1` a second time, `/dev/bcache` suddenly exists, as does `/sys/fs/bcache` and `/sys/fs/block/bcache0` etc.

A weird side-note is that running `make-bcache -B` for the second time in a script (even with sleeps in between) does not fix the issue, but running it manually does.

Once bcache has initiated properly it stays stable, also after reboots and VM-relocations. You can read the configuration scripts at https://github.com/okke-formsma/azure-bcache.

Does anyone have a clue how to enable bcache on my ubuntu 16.04 machine without having to resort to a double manual `make-bcache -B xxx`?

[edit] According to [the archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bcache#.2Fsys.2Ffs.2Fbcache.2F_does_not_exist) not having a /sys/fs/bcache means that "The kernel you booted is not bcache enabled", however that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

The module was not loaded by the kernel. Doing a `sudo modprobe bcache` made all bcache functionality available without weird workarounds.